# Converting a slightly warped polygon lattice with irregular edges to a raster

Tags: qgis, geoprocessing, rasterization

I have a problem which has been frustrating me for a while. I have a lattice of polygons which is slightly warped due to unknown CRS transformations & distortions, enough so that the side lengths vary from about +/- 15m. There are also holes inside and there are irregular edges. This pic shows a subset of the grid:

[image]

I need to convert this into a numpy array so that I can apply a moving window function onto it.

So far I have tried:

1. Finding the original projection so that all the edge length discrepancies are negligible - no luck
2. Creating another point lattice on top of it, hoping that despite the distortions, there would still be a 1:1 parity for a point to a square - no luck again, the lattice is too big and the points eventually get out of sync and skip a square

I feel like I am out of ideas on this, but I really need to get this into a raster/numpy array. The only limitation is not to use ArcGIS because I don't have a license.

Comment: @BERA; There is no polygon where it is black, but it is clear that the gaps would "fit" the same squares inside, provided they were distorted and warped the same way as the original dataset. I would leave these as NODATA in the hypothetical output raster/numpy array

Comment: Is it possible to rotate them straight using Affine transform

Comment: @BERA: No, because the distortion is not uniform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it after finding out that there had been some more work done by a colleague. It turns out that we also had a database which contained a sort of "locally-defined" topology. A table contained a `cell_id` column, `neighbour_id` column and a `direction`, in which each row would represent a connection between two cells, along with a cardinal direction (`N`, `NE`, `E` ...). I then followed these steps:

1. Convert the table into a directed graph (I used pandas and NetworkX) whose edges contained the `direction` value.
2. Initialize a square numpy array filled with `NaN` whose width and height far exceeded 2x the number of rows and columns of the polygon dataset
3. Create a tree via a depth first search of the edges from an arbitrary node, which was assigned the row/col coordinates of side_length/2 (where side_length is the width & height of the numpy array from step 2)
4. Traverse this tree, assigning a new row/col coordinate based on the previous (already assigned during traversal) node's row/col coordinate and its direction (e.g. if the previous node coordinate was assigned as (10, 10) and the direction is `E`, then the next node's row/col coordinate is assigned as (10, 11))
5. Cut off the top/bottom and sides of the numpy array where the entire row or column (respectively) was all `NaN`
6. Repeat this process if necessary if there are multiple "islands" of cells

As far as deriving this "local topology" definition, I didn't do it. Sorry if this is a bit of a cop out, but I would assume that you could do something where you start at the centroid of a cell and go in each cardinal direction by the (approximate) side length of the cells (or sqrt(2)*side_length for diagonals) and then assign the appropriate cardinal direction based on which other cell you intersect. then go to this newly-found cell's centroid and start the process again.

Answer (score 1):

1. Georeference by coordinates *in polygon units* rather than geographic. That is,  (0,0) for the polygon in the bottom left corner, etc. You'll need a lot of points and a non linear transform function, which is available in QGIS.
2. Then take the value of each polygon as z and its x,y coordinate as an x,y,z ungridded dataset.
3. Grid the x,y,z data to a raster and apply your filters to the resulting gridded data.

Comment: I'm not familiar with georeferencing a vector layer in QGIS, how do you do that?

Comment: Try the Vector Bender plugin.